# Heavily skewed distribution -- transform to normal?

Tags: data-transformation, skewness, lags

[image]

I have the above distribution of data -- two things to note:

1)  These are all integers [the x axis is measuring lag -- the number of days between an initial event and a final event], and 2) There actually are values going out towards 400, 500, etc., but they don't show up well on this chart because they're so few compared to the 20000+ "2" values.

My audience here is interested in the average view of this data.  When I reported the true average of 35, however, it communicated the wrong idea, since 95+% of the events happen in 8 days or less.

I know that median would be a more reasonable measure here, but this particular audience is so non-mathy that median is not a clear measure.

Therefore, I have been tasked with removing any outliers from this data in order to get a more representative "average" number.  I know removing data is generally avoided, but I've been specifically requested to do it in this situation.

Is there a way to transform this data to a more normal distribution so then standard deviation can be used on it?  If not, what is the best way to transform and handle outliers in this particular set of data?

I don't have much background in statistics so any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you want to remove the outliers? Don't you think that it would be easier to explain your audience what median is compared to explaining the transformations you used, rationale for them etc.? "Half of the values are higher and half are lower then this" is not really complicated idea to explain and it seems at first sight to be more reasonable.

Comment: The statement that 95% of the value happen in 8 days or less is a statement about a quantile so if they understand that why can they not understand the median?

Comment: I initially put together the median view as part of a report, but it was returned and I was asked to move forward with the average (removing extreme outliers) instead.  I understand it's not ideal, but is there any statistical method that can handle such situations?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsorizing